# ARM template regression issue with metric name 'Percentage CPU'

Tags: azure, templates, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-manager

I am using a template from Azure Quickstart. One that I have used many times. **It is unchanged since the last time I used it successfully**. Here is the
[template](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates%2Fmaster%2Flansa-vmss-windows-autoscale-sql-database%2Fazuredeploy.json)

[image]

This error is produced near the end of the deployment and may be viewed through the Resource Group 'Deployments' link.

Reminder: its a regression issue. Is this a feature that has been deliberately removed or is it a defect in Azure?

Comment: I can't seem to deploy the template with some weird error `CustomerDeniedServicePlanAccess`, do you know the case for this? Also, the metric definition looks fine

Comment: I am also getting an error near the end of deployment for Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets. My error is as below:                                    "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'FirstInstall'. Error message: \"Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\"."

Comment: Are you using the default values for the parameters?

Comment: @juvchan I am using the default values for all of the parameters

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks for confirming the metric definition

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: @juvchan I'm testing it now

Comment: @juvchan it is now working. I changed nothing. Even exactly the same passwords! It must have been fixed behind the scenes.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful to you, kindly mark it as helpful or mark it as acceptable answer

Comment: @juvchan It was helpful in that it prompted me to retest it. So I've marked it as useful. I think my answer is the most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to deploy your [template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/lansa-vmss-windows-autoscale-sql-database/azuredeploy.json) above successfully at the second attempt.
I am using the default values for the all parameters with default values except for **trace** which I set to "**Y**" for error tracing if any.

My first attempt failed because I wrongly updated the **GitBranch** parameter to **master** which it shouldn't be. The default value is correct.

Hence, this should not be any issue with the template as well as the parameters with default values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was just transitory. The presumption is that the issue was fixed behind the scenes.